# How to sell music in Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one, music

How do I go about selling music in the Ubuntu One Music Store? I have some clients that are interested in putting their catalog for sale on Ubuntu One.

Answer (score 7):

You would need to get your music into the store at 7-Digital (https://www.7digital.com/), for all the countries which Ubuntu One has store fronts for, to have your music appear in the Ubuntu One Music Store. You cannot directly upload music to the store, for sale, such as you can with applications.